# subplot with shared axis but different ticks and labels

Tags: matplotlib

I make a plot with different subplots (using gridspec.GridSpec). Two subplots share the same x-axis (sharex=ax1 in the definition of the second subplot).

However, as one subplot shows the indices of the chronologically sorted data, and the second subplot shows the corresponding decades, I want seperate ticks and labels for the x-axes of both plots. 
This seems not possible, a unique set of labels and ticks are assigned to both subplots. Until now, I can only:

1. use different x-axes and thus assign two sets of ticks and labels.
   In that case, the axes are not alligned although
   ax1.set_xlim([start, stop]) are similarly defined for both subplots
   [image: figure]
2. use a common x-axis and one set of ticks and labels

I do not find a solution for this on the internet. Is someone able to help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: In fact, I got help from a colleague (Stijn Van Hoey) to find a solution that combines the shared x axis and the different ticks and labels. I hope you don't mind that I don't create an example anymore? Basically, the solution is this: we created 3 x axes: 
1. Axis of top-graph (subplot 1) that shows corresponding ticks and labels
2. Axis of bottom-graph (subplot 2) that has sharex with subplot 1, but ticks and labels are invisible.
3. Extra x axis (add_axis) located on bottom of subplot 2 that shows the wanted ticks and labels.